# Speed up cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to cypher and don't really understand the tuning process. So I thought I could get some help here.

I'm creating routing app and I'm loading GTFS data set to neo4j. I have around 1.2 mil TripStops and i need to create transfer relationships between them (same stop_id). I made really dumb query to do that:

```
MATCH (a:TripStop) With a Match(b:TripStop) 
With b create (a)-[r:Prestup]->(b)
```

~166 000 000 000 estimated rows

which I "upgraded" to:

```
MATCH (a:TripStop) With a Match(b:TripStop) 
With b where id(b)>id(a) and b.trip_id<>a.trip_id and b.stop_id=a.stop_id create (a)-[r:Prestup]->(b)
```

~41 000 000 000 estimated rows

but I don't really know how to speed things up so it doesn't take ages.

I will be glad for any advice, trick

EDIT:

I made some research and made indexes for stop_id and the query now results in: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt2ig.png)

which is still not great (187,166,925 estimated rows for the full data set), but progress I guess, any idea how to speed it up even better?

Comment: I can't think of a way to make this faster, but you've probably done the right things so far, by avoiding Eager agregations, adding indexing and not using MERGE when CREATE will work - sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Your queries are flawed. `WITH b` means that `a` is now out of scope (WITH controls what variables are in scope; anything not included is dropped from scope). The usage of `a` afterwards is binding to all nodes, not the :TripStop nodes you matched to earlier.

Comment: Also estimated rows aren't something to rely on. These are often ballpark or orders of magnitude estimations for use by the planner. Don't rely on them as any indicator of true performance. You could use PROFILE instead (you get actual row counts and db hit info) but it does actually execute the query.

Comment: Lastly with a large data set you'll want to create relationships in batches, not all in a single transaction. Get APOC Procedures and use [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/periodic-execution/)